# dojo dialog position

Tags: dojo

I have an iFrame which has a dijit.Dialog. Since this iframe is small in width and height, I was wondering if I could place this dialog in the parent window somehow. 
I tried to do:

```
 var parent_pane = parent.dijit.byId("testpane"); //testpane is in the parent window
 dijit.byId("linkedResourcePopup").placeAt(parent_pane);
 dijit.byId("linkedResourcePopup").show();
```

This gives me a javascript error in firebug:

```
_16c.appendChild is not a function
```

Is this possible.?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because `parent.dijit.byId("testpane").appendChild` is not a function.

You need to pass a DOM node to `placeAt`. You can access the parent widgets node via `parent_pane.domNode`.

Comment: So you mean, since it belongs to a different DOM, it cannot be done?

Comment: No, it can be done. You just need to pass parent_pane.domNode to the placeAt function instead of just the parent_pane widget

Answer (score 0):

placeAt receives a domNode according to:

```
dojo.place(node, refNode, pos);
```

**node:** Can be a String or a DOM node.
**refNode:** Can be a string (interpreted as an id of a DOM node) or a DOM node.
**pos:** Optional argument. Can be a number or one of the following strings: “before”, “after”, “replace”, “only”, “first”, or “last”. If omitted, “last” is assumed.

I think what you should do is:

```
 var parent_pane = parent.dijit.byId("testpane"); //testpane is in the parent window
 dijit.byId("linkedResourcePopup").placeAt(parent_pane.domNode);
 dijit.byId("linkedResourcePopup").show();
```